# How to get the records of X and its referrals in one query?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join

I have got 3 tables.

```
Orders                       Clients                    Referrals
-----                        -----                      -----
id                           id                         id
total_price                  name                       name
receiver_client_id           status                     client_id
```

While adding order, sometimes the receiver is **CLIENT**, sometimes **REFERRAL**, so *receiver_client_id* can have both *client_id* or *referral_id*. **Referrals** are added by **Clients**, that's why I store *client_id* in **referrals** table.

I want to get all the orders of a client who's id is "15032" as well as its referral's orders in one query. Is it possible?

Sample data:

```
Orders                 Clients                  Referals
----                   ----                     ----
1, 350, 15032          15010, "Alex", 1         7809100, "Jay", 15010
2, 440, 16500          15011, "Jacob", 1        7809101, "Jean",15010
3, 210, 18023          15012, "Sam", 0          7809102, "Hew", 15011
4, 900, 15032          15032, "John", 1         7809123, "Aldo",15032
5, 330, 7809123        15040, "Sandy", 0        7809124, "Sew", 15032
```

Expected result:

```
1, 350, 15032
4, 900, 15032
5, 330, 7809123
```

What i did:

```
select * from orders AS o JOIN
  (SELECT id FROM clients where id = 15172
   UNION
  SELECT id FROM referals where referals.client_id = 15172) AS c
on o.receiver_client_id = c.id
```

But it's not correct. **How am I gonna know that referal_id is not someone else's client_id?** After 1 year, **client_ids gonna increment to 7809100** (same as referal_id). Aren't they gonna be mixed?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Write one query to get clients, another to get referrals. Combine them with `UNION` to get both together.

Comment: @TheImpaler Please check the edited version

Comment: @ProfomStat I don't see a query with your post.  If you don't post your wrong query, how are we supposed to help you fix it???

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders o
JOIN Clients c ON c.id = o.receiver_client_id
LEFT JOIN Referrals r ON r.client_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = 15032
```

Then you `UNION` the Clients and Referrals table first.  This will get you orders from both clients and referrals

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, name
    FROM Clients
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT id, name
    FROM Referrals
) t
JOIN Orders o ON o.receiver_client_id = t.id
```

Comment: If you only want the referral info, change the select to `SELECT DISTINCT r.id, r.name`

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is UNION two tables together, one for the orders, and one for the referrals.  To get the orders where the referral number links back to the client id, a JOIN will be needed:

```
SELECT 
*
from orders where receiver_client_id in ($receivers)
UNION
select * from
(
  SELECT o.id, o.total_price, o.receiver_client_id 
  from orders
  inner join referrals r
  on o.receiver_client_id = r.id
  where r.client_id in ($receivers)
)
```

Comment: Please check edited version